# How to set defined value for each field present in PDF Form using PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

How to set defined value for each and every field present in PDF Form,
Consider that I have 5 fields in my PDF form say 2 Text box (First Name and Last Name) two Check box (Check_1,Check_2) , 2 Radio Button(Male,Female) and then at last i have another Text box (Address) , Now I have to define or set a value each and every field say 1 for First Name and 2 for Last Name , 3 for Check_1 and goes on till 7 for Address 
Below is the piece of code to define the value for each field but I'm facing some issue while setting up value for Radio button fields 
when it comes to Male and Female field it makes displays "1" for male and female for other fields it displays the correct value

Can any one help me out please ...

Thanks

```
List FieldTypes = form.getFields();
    PDField pdfFields;
        for (int i = 0; i < FieldTypes.size(); i++) {

            pdfFields = (PDField) FieldTypes.get(i);
            String type = null;

            if (pdfFields instanceof PDTextbox) {
                type = "TextBox";
                String iAsString = Integer.toString(i);
                pdfFields.setValue(iAsString);
                System.out.println("Text" + "   "+ pdfFields.getFullyQualifiedName());
             } else if (pdfFields instanceof PDCheckbox) {
                type = "CheckBox";
                String iAsString = Integer.toString(i);
                System.out.println(iAsString);
                System.out.println("CheckBox" + "   "+ pdfFields.getFullyQualifiedName());
            } else if (pdfFields instanceof PDRadioCollection) {

                List kids = pdfFields.getKids();
                for (Object kid : kids) {
                      if (kid instanceof PDCheckbox) {
                      PDCheckbox checkbox = (PDCheckbox) kid;
                      String Name = checkbox.getOnValue();
                      String iAsString = Integer.toString(i);
                      System.out.println(iAsString);
                      type = "RadioButton";
                      System.out.println("RadioButton"+"  "+checkbox.getOnValue());
                      }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I even added up increment statement i++ it works fine for Radio button fields but it misses out the last field

Answer (score 0):

Based on doc i think getOnValue() method returns only the status like checked or not checked. Can you try getPartialName(),getValue(),getFullyQualifiedName(),getAlternateFieldName() or any other methods.

Answer (score 0):

With Radio Buttons you have to figure out what the "On Values" are, similar to a Checkbox. However there are multiple On values for Radio Buttons, so its a different method.

For example, if I run this against a  Radio Button group where you have to choose from Checking Savings or Money Market, we would see this printed:

**Type of Account (org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDRadioButton)**

**Radio Button**

**[Savings, Checking, Money Market]**

```
public void list(PDField field)
{
    System.out.println(field.getFullyQualifiedName() + " (" + field.getClass().getName() +")");

    if(field instanceof PDRadioButton){
        System.out.println("Radio Button");
        System.out.println(((PDRadioButton) field).getOnValues());
    }
}
```

If I wanted to have the "Checking" button checked, I would set the field's value equal to "Checking".

Hopefully this helps.